# i20 front rear wheel tilted inside!

Tags: alignment

The upper half of front rear wheel of i20 is bending or tilting inside a bit approx. 1 inch. However, the left rear wheel is not. No bending either sides at all.

Is this normal?? How do I correct to the same position like the right rear wheel?? All 3 remaining wheels are ok.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely not normal, it could lead to uneven tire wear very quickly, and depending on the cause, more severe consequences while on the road. It's hard to say specifically what the problem is, but I'd take it to a mechanic to check the structural integrity first, and then an alignment shop if that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a suspension bush that has failed.

Had one go on my car and it ripped the inside edge off the tire very quickly.

Get it checked, it is either a bush or a failed component.

Comment: Ok...I have checked the rear shocker and springs which both shows no signs of any physical damaged or any fluid leakages!!!

Comment: Did you check any of the suspension bushes as suggested?

Comment: Yes check and no sign of any damages or leakages.

Comment: How did you check them? What did you look for?

Comment: Any signs of physical damaged, bent etc on the shocker and any leakages from the shocker too. No such signs.

Comment: You have the evidence  find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the rear wheel is tilted at the wrong angle. i20s use twist beam rear suspension so there's only a small number of things that could be wrong.

There's 5 possible causes that I can think of:

1. The wheel is bent.
2. Rear wheel bearing has failed. This will make a horrible noise when you're driving.
3. Twist beam bushing has disintegrated. This is probably the cheapest one to fix.
4. Rear wheel bearing unit (or stub axle, as it's also called) bolts are loose and it's coming off. If it's just a larger version of the suspension on the Getz, it will be held on by 4 bolts.
5. Twist beam is bent. Usually caused by some sort of accident.

You can test if 2, 3 or 4 are the cause by jacking up the car and pulling on some bits of it so see if they're loose. With the car jacked up, the wheel should turn freely (unless the handbrake/parking brake is on) but should not wobble at all. You should be able to pull and push hard on the wheel and twist it at any angle and it will feel like you're pulling the whole car. If you can feel a knock as you pull the wheel it probably means that the wheel bearing has failed, even if the wheel doesn't seem to move much.
With the car jacked up (don't crawl under it) have a look at the joint/hinge in front of the rear wheel, where it connects to the car body. The gaps around the joint should be the same on both sides of the car. Try pulling on the twist beam near the joint, you should not be able to move it at all. If you can move it, the twist beam rubber bushing has failed.